# How to find the count of every character in string in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have string `"AABBCCCDEEEE"` and expected result is

```
AA - 2
BB - 2
CC - 3
D  - 1
E  - 4
```

Comment: I didn't realize that `'AA'` is a character.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it is not. He meant there are 2 A characters.

Comment: @CetinBasoz . . . So `'CC'` means there are two `'C'` characters?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes in string there are 3 and obviously it is a typo not to write CCC there. Looks like you are trying to be picky.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, what is expected result for "AAXXAA" ?

Comment: @daniherrera, A - 4, X - 2. I think even you could do the simple math.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the answer to this question in SQL Server:

```
with Temp as (
               select substring('AABBCCCDEEEE',1,1) as character, 1 as number
               union all
               select substring('AABBCCCDEEEE',1+number,1) as character, number + 1 
               from Temp
               where number < len('AABBCCCDEEEE')
             )
select character, count(1) as count
from Temp
group by character option(maxrecursion 20);
```

[Result Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAoQk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following script to split one by one character and store them into a Temporary table. Finally apply GROUP BY/COUNT to get your desired result.

**Note:** This is workable in MSSQL. For other database, you can use the same logic

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX) = 'AABBCCCDEEEE'
DECLARE @LoopCountSt INT = 1
DECLARE @LoopCountEnd INT = LEN(@STR)

DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(
    val VARCHAR(1)
)

WHILE @LoopCountSt <= @LoopCountEnd
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TempTable(val)
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@STR,@LoopCountSt,1)

    SET @LoopCountSt = @LoopCountSt + 1
END

SELECT val, COUNT(*) Total_Count
FROM @TempTable
GROUP BY Val
```

Output is-

```
val Total_Count
A   2
B   2
C   3
D   1
E   4
```